# Concat string if condition, else do nothing

Tags: python, string, if-statement, concatenation

I want to concat few strings together, and add the last one only if a boolean condition is True.
Like this (a, b and c are strings):

```
something = a + b + (c if <condition>)
```

But Python does not like it. Is there a nice way to do it without the else option?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Yeah, the condition will evaluate to either 1 or 0, and multiplication result will either give you the string or an empty string. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/jE9zYp). However, that is oh so obfuscated and not straight-forward, I'd rather refrain from using it unless you *have to* compress the code as much as possible (is it for code golf)?

Comment: because people here tend to avoid the else if not needed, wanted to follow that guideline.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try something below without using `else`. It works by indexing empty string when condition False (0) and indexing string `c` when condition True (1)

```
something = a + b + ['', c][condition]
```

I am not sure why you want to avoid using else, otherwise, the code below seems more readable:

```
something = a + b + (c if condition else '')
```

Answer (score 7):

This should work for simple scenarios -

```
something = ''.join([a, b, c if condition else ''])
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, but it's not very Pythonic:

```
something = a + b + c * condition
```

This will work because `condition * False` will return `''`, while `condition * True` will return original `condition`. However, You must be careful here, `condition` could also be `0` or `1`, but any higher number or any literal will break the code.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a nice way to do it without the **else** option?

Well, yes:

```
something = ''.join([a, b])
if condition:
    something = ''.join([something, c])
```

But I don't know whether you mean literally without else, or without the whole if statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
a_list = ['apple', 'banana,orange', 'strawberry']
b_list = []

for i in a_list:
    for j in i.split(','):
        b_list.append(j)

print(b_list)
```